# Getting "control characters in the file names" message when validating archive

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios7, app-store

I want to submit my app to app store.When I validated the archive in Xcode, it failed and showed

`Your package contains a file 'HuaHeForUp.app/Mcj33x@2x.jpg' with a name that contains invalid characters.Avoid using control characters in the file names.`

And many image files also have the same problem.I don't know why.I don't see strange characters in those file names.

Comment: So, what do you see for this image, for example?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it seems to be about user error in Xcode project management.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting that image in .png format in your application. If it does not fix this, add the image again to your app and make sour that "copy to destination" is checked.

Comment: Thank you.I changed file names and add images again to solve the problem.